# how to perform a generalised eigendecomposition here?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to implement an laplacian eigenmaps algorithm, which consists of:

1) construct a graph (I use kNN and say that there is an edge to the k nearest neighbours)

2) associate each edge with a weight

3) define the diagonal (which is the sum of the row placed diagonally)

4) perform the generalised eigendecomposition (which should be Lv = lambda*D*v, where L and D is computed in the code below)

I think this can be solved somehow with scipy.linalg.eig(vals), but I dont understand how to input my two matrices correctly. Can someone help me in understanding how to perform the generalised eigendecomposition step?

```
import numpy as np
import random as r
from math import exp as exp
from scipy.spatial import distance

def rweights((vectors,features)):
    return 1 * np.random.random_sample((vectors,features)) - 0

def vEuclidean(v, m):
   return np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: distance.euclidean(v,x), 1, m)

def mEuclideans(m):
   return np.apply_along_axis(lambda v: vEuclidean(v,m), 1, m)

def neighbours(vector, neigh):
   size = (vector.shape[0] - neigh)
   for i in range(1,size):
      vector[np.argmax(vector)] = 0.0
   return vector

def kNN(m, k):
    me = mEuclideans(m)
    return np.array(map(lambda v: neighbours(v, k), me))

def diag(m):
    sums = np.sum(m,1)
    (vectors,features) = m.shape
    zeros = np.zeros(vectors*features).reshape((vectors,features))
    for i in range(features):
        zeros[i][i] = sums[i]
    return zeros

def vectorWeight(v, sigma):
      f = lambda x: exp((-(x)/(sigma**2)))
      size = v.shape[0]
      for i in range(size):
          v[i] = f(v[i])
      return v 

def weight(m):
    return np.array(np.apply_along_axis(lambda v: vectorWeight(v,0.5), 1, m))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    np.random.seed(666)
    m = rweights((5,3))
    w = weight(kNN(m, 2))
    D = diag(w)
    L = D-w
```

Comment: The array parameters `a` and `b` are explained in the docstring of `scipy.linalg.eig` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html).  These should correspond to your `L` and `D`.  Have you tried that?  If so, please describe in more detail the problem that you have.

Comment: @warren. So scipy.linalg.eig(L, D) would return eigenvalues corresponding to lambda (w in the doc), and v (vl normalised eigenvectors in doc)?

Comment: With the default arguments `left=False, right=True`, the columns of the second return value are the (right) generalized eigenvectors (`vr` in the docstring).  Those would be your `v`.

Comment: @warren. Thanks. I will check tomorrow, but that might help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, 
this answer is aided by Warrens help (so he deserves the credit), but I found a video on spectral clustering https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ln0mgyvXNQE, where he uses laplacian on a graph. I thought it would be nice to check my implementation against his results. Thus, I added:

```
from scipy.linalg import eig    

def distanceM():
    return np.array([[0.0,0.8,0.6, 0.1,0.0,0.0], 
    [0.8,0.0,0.9,0.0,0.0,0.0], [0.6,0.9,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.2], 
    [0.1,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.6,0.7],[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.6,0.0,0.8]
    [0.0,0.0,0.2,0.7,0.8,0.0]])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    w = distanceM()
    D = diag(w)
    L = D-w
    w,vr = eig(L)
    print vr
```

I find that I get the same laplacian matrix, and also the same eigenvectors (second column of vr).